# How to decide if a component should be controllable by its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular, frontend

Some of the components in my APP only has the option for the its parent to provide an initial value. But beyond the initial value, the parent cannot control the component's state or value.

Is this bad design?

Is it always the case that a component be controllable by its parent?

Comment: Does the parent need to know the change that the component made? If not then no. If you do then just use @Output(), otherwise some form of state management would be helpful even just a basic rxjs implementation of state management.

Comment: No, It is not always the case that a component be controllable by its parent. If the parent needs to know the child component then yes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key concepts about new React hooks is allows to components has your own state. By the way, i think you should use Context API from React to shared data or state between components, also you should use Redux if you think your app it will growing in the future.

I will wait your feedback.